How calculate dB SPL from microphone signal
I have UMIK-1(24bit depth) and calibration file for it, where there is sens factor in dbFS and mic correction. I wrote a script in Python, where I receive a signal from the microphone and I can no longer imagine how to correctly process it in dB SPL.
I know how to use mic correction, but I absolutely dont understand how to use sens factor
I used a lot of combinations of sens factor and my signal, but it doesn't work
UPDATE:
I'm not sure, that Umik-1 has gain, but Windows OS finds it as "Umik-1 (Gain 18dB)", but I'm going to use my script on Raspberry OS. Calibration files looks like:
"Sens Factor =-2.082dB, SERNO: 7943342"
10.054  -4.9944
10.179  -4.8272
10.306  -4.6632
10.434  -4.5024
10.564  -4.3447
10.696  -4.1902
10.829  -4.0388
10.964  -3.8904
11.1    -3.7451
11.238  -3.6027
11.378  -3.4634
11.52   -3.3269
11.663  -3.1934
...
20016.816   1.5876
my script on Python(all imports work correctly):
def convert_to_int24(data) -> np.ndarray:
    data_np = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8)
    data_np = data_np.reshape(-1, 3)
    data_int24 = (
        data_np[:, 0].astype(np.int32)
        + (data_np[:, 1].astype(np.int32) << 8)
        + (data_np[:, 2].astype(np.int32) << 16)
    )

    return data_int24

def ac_rms(signal):
    # sig = signal - np.mean(signal)
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(signal.astype(np.dtype(np.int64))**2))


def main():
    # connect to Umik-1
    s = create_stream()
    s.start_stream()

    freqs, vals = get_calibration_data()

    interp_correction_function = interp1d(freqs, 10 ** (vals / 10), kind='linear')
    interpolated_correction_values = interp_correction_function(np.linspace(20, 20_000, 20_000 - 20))

    # Since the sampling frequency is 48 kHz, I decided to increase the correction with zero values.
    interpolated_correction_values = np.append(np.zeros(20), interpolated_correction_values)
    interpolated_correction_values = np.append(interpolated_correction_values, np.zeros(4000))

    while True:
        signal = s.read(CHUNK, exception_on_overflow=False)

        mic_data_bytes = np.frombuffer(signal)

        data_int24 = convert_to_int24(data=mic_data_bytes)

        spectrum = rfft(data_int24)
        abs_spectrum = RATE * np.abs(spectrum)[:RATE // 2]

        filtered_spectrum = abs_spectrum - interpolated_correction_values

        corrected_mic_data = irfft(filtered_spectrum * RATE / 2).astype(int)

        rms = ac_rms(corrected_mic_data)
        # I inderstand that this SENS_FACTOR's conversion has zero efficiency
        SPL = 10 * np.log10(rms) - SENS_FACTOR
        print(np.round(a=SPL, decimals=1))```


I updated my question

A couple of comments here: 1) Not sure what RATE is (I assume sampling rate?), 2) I think you don’t have to multiply by 2 when using the rfft function of numpy and the same goes for irfft, 3) You may want to use vals/10 to convert correction values to linear, 4) It is not clear to me how exactly you convert negative $\textrm{dB}$ to linear values and still get real values back (maybe want to double-check?), 5) When you apply the sensitivity factor you convert it to linear and right away back to $\textrm{dB}$ but I don’t understand why.


Yes, RATE is sampling rate. 2) But to normalize the amplitudes we should divide spectrum by its length, right? And length equals RATE // 2. 3) Ok, thank you, I'll do it. 4) Сan you clarify which line of code you are talking about?  5) Yes, I know, I'll fix it


2) That is true only if you process half a second in every iteration of your loop, otherwise, the length of the data vector is…… the number of samples you get! 4) Cancel that, it was an error on my side, I apologise if it confused you.

Thanks for all your corrections. but it still doesn't work. The script always outputs 96.4 dB, even if I put on a calibrator with 94 dB on 1 kHz

I believe you’re not that far from the solution. I suggest you try and tweak a couple of values, such as the length of the data vector, use fft and ifft instead of their real counterparts (make sure to get the scalings correctly), the sensitivity, double check the correction is applied correctly and whatever comes to mind to make it give the correct results. This is definitely not the “scientific” way to go about it but when you get the correct result, the changes you made may hint to something. I have a feeling you should start with the conversion to int24, as you are now (cont.)

(cont.ed) converting to int32 with the 8 MSBs zero. This seems correct but the dB$_{\textrm{FS}}$ value you would get for these numbers is not necessarily the same you would get with actual int24 values. This is just a suggestion though...

1. Intro
I don’t have experience with the specific microphone, but based on the fact that the sensitivity factor is in dB$_{\textrm{FS}}$ leads me to assume it is a digital microphone.
2. Possible solution
Since there’s not much info in the question, I will try to provide a “generic” solution that hopefully will work for your case too.
The steps you would have to follow are:

Correct the response of the microphone.
Apply the sensitivity factor.

2.1 Microphone response correction
Here we can distinguish two cases.

Correction in the time domain (impulse response).
Correction in the frequency domain (frequency response).

2.1.1 Time domain correction
If you have the mic correction as an impulse response, all you have to do is to convolve the correction with your signal. You can do that with numpy.convolve (I am not a Python user so if you know a better way go for it).
Subsequently, you can convert your data to the frequency domain via the Fourier transform (you can use numpy.fft.rfft for that).
2.1.2 Frequency domain correction
If the correction is provided as a frequency response, there are a couple of things you could do. If the frequency response provided is a complex vector, you could very well calculate the impulse response via the inverse Fourier transform (you can use numpy.fft.irfft) and then convolve with your data as in 2.1.1 above.
Alternatively, if your correction is a real vector representing the magnitude correction, or if you don’t want to go the “time domain way”, you will have to transform your data vector to the frequency domain. Again, you can use numpy.fft.rfft for that. There are a couple of caveats here you have to take care of.
To apply the frequency response correction to your data, you have to multiply the frequency domain representation of the two. For this to happen, the two vectors (data and correction) have to be of the same length. If you are not doing frame/block processing, there is a high probability that the two vectors will not have the same length. In this case, you have to do something about it. The “easiest” (and possibly a bit “naive”) way I would suggest would be to use Python functions to make the correction vector have the same length as your data. The whole process would look something like the following (assuming your data vector is data and the correction vector is correction)
correction = numpy.fft.irfft(correction)
correction = numpy.fft.rfft(correction, n = 2 * len(data) - 1, norm = “forward")
correctData = numpy.multiply(correction, data)

A couple of things to note here. First, it can be considered somewhat naive and redundant to convert to the time domain and then back to the frequency domain, but I believe this is a rather easy way to achieve what you want. Alternatively, you could convolve the time domain data since you already got the correction “curve” to the time domain. Second, in the code snippet above, I assumed the correction curve is a one-sided spectrum. If this is not the case, you should replace numpy.fft.irfft with numpy.fft.ifft. Finally, note that the norm argument was added in v1.10 and the needed value forward was added in v1.20 of numpy. If you don’t have access to it, you have to divide the vector by its length.
2.2 Sensitivity correction
 Since you have corrected the response of the microphone, in theory, the response at each frequency will be the same (please note that this is rarely, if ever, the case). This means that you can now apply the sensitivity factor to convert the values that you have to some “meaningful” physical value. 
Since, as you suggest in the comments, your sensitivity factor is supposed to be used with Root-Mean-Square (RMS) values (like most sensitivity factors I am familiar with), this is the process you have to follow to calculate the Sound Pressure Level (SPL) from your signal.
As you mention in the question, the sensitivity is given in $\textrm{dB}_{\textrm{FS}}$, so you should use it with $\textrm{dB}_{\textrm{FS}}$ values only. You do know that you are dealing with $24$-bit samples you can calculate the value that corresponds to $0 \, \textrm{dB}_{\textrm{FS}}$. So, trying to put all those things together we have the following steps:
2.2.1 RMS calculation
Before discussing (some of) your options here, let’s first show how to calculate RMS values. The mathematical formula is
$$ y_{\textrm{RMS}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1} x^{2} \!\left[ i \right]} \tag{1} \label{1} $$
where I used the “programming convention” of setting the first index to be $i = 0$. If you’d like to start from $i = 1$, then you should also change the upper limit from $N - 1$ to $N$.
Now, you have several options here. One and the easiest (and possibly most “naive”) is to calculate the RMS value of the whole file and get an estimate of the SPL of the whole file. You can do that like
rms = numpy.sqrt(numpy.mean(data.astype(numpy.dtype(numpy.int64))**2))

where I have also set the calculations to be performed with higher resolution numbers to avoid overflows (taken from a comment from this StackOverflow answer). If your measurement is rather short, or the source is stationary (that is, it doesn’t change its characteristics with time) then this may be adequate for what you are trying to achieve.
However, what is usually done, to catch the changes in non-stationary sounds is to calculate the RMS value of frames of data that may, or may not overlap with each other. The process is identical to what we showed above for the RMS calculation of the whole file, with the exception that now, $N$ is the length of the frame, which is less than the length of the data vector and quite often is a power of two, but this is not necessary. In this case, the RMS value at discrete time index $n$ is given by
$$ y_{\textrm{RMS}} \!\left[ n \right] = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = n - N + 1}^{n} x^{2} \!\left[ i \right]} \tag{2} \label{2} $$
A special case is when the window overlap is almost the entire window but a single sample. You can think of this as sliding the window across your signal, one sample at a time. This is what is called a running or moving RMS (the same terminology is used for other kinds of processes such as averaging - moving average - and median - moving median -). averages. For more information about the RMS and running/moving RMS you can have a look at this question and its answers.
There is a rather efficient recursive formula which you can use to calculate the running/moving RMS of a signal on a “per-sample” basis. You can reach it as follows:
$$
\begin{split}
y_{\textrm{RMS}} \!\left[ n \right] & = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = n - N + 1}^{n} x^{2} \!\left[ i \right]} \implies \\
y^{2}_{\textrm{RMS}} \!\left[ n \right] & = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = n - N + 1}^{n} x^{2} \!\left[ i \right] = \\
& = \frac{x^{2} \!\left[ n \right]}{N} + \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = n - N + 1}^{n - 1} x^{2} \!\left[ i \right] = \\
& = \frac{x^{2} \!\left[ n \right]}{N} - \frac{x^{2} \!\left[ n - N \right]}{N} + \frac{x^{2} \!\left[ n - N \right]}{N} + \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = n - N + 1}^{n - 1} x^{2} \!\left[ i \right] = \\
& = \frac{x^{2} \!\left[ n \right]}{N} - \frac{x^{2} \!\left[ n - N \right]}{N} + \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = n - N}^{n - 1} x^{2} \!\left[ i \right] = \\
& = \frac{x^{2} \!\left[ n \right]}{N} - \frac{x^{2} \!\left[ n - N \right]}{N} + y_{\textrm{RMS}}^{2} \!\left[ n - 1 \right] \implies \\
y_{\textrm{RMS}} \!\left[ n \right] & = \sqrt{\frac{x^{2} \!\left[ n \right]}{N} - \frac{x^{2} \!\left[ n - N \right]}{N} + y_{\textrm{RMS}}^{2} \!\left[ n - 1 \right]}
\end{split} \tag{3} \label{3}
$$
So, by using the RMS value for the last/previous discrete time sample you can calculate the new RMS value for the current discrete time index by “removing” the effect of the oldest sample and “replacing” it with the newest. It is imporant to note that in this case, you will get an RMS value per sample.
Things to note: You have to keep in mind that the size/length of the frame/window does affect the result, with longer windows being slower to respond to abrupt changes. Additionally, when you use the moving/running RMS, you have to keep in mind that the first N RMS values returned will not be the correct values, because for the first $N - 1$ estimates, some of the $x \left[ n \right]$ values will have to be zero, unless you start processing from the $N$th sample onwards.
2.2.2 Application of the sensitivity factor
After you have calculated the RMS value(s) of interest, you are ready to apply the sensitivity factor. Now, the sensitivity factor tells you what is the output of your apparatus when a known quantity is measured. I will assume that the factor you have refers to what is usually used in acoustics, which is the $1 \, \textrm{Pa}$ corresponding to approximately $94 \, \textrm{dB}_{\textrm{SPL}}, \textrm{re} 20 \, \mu \textrm{Pa}$.
So, the value that you are given is the RMS value you should measure when the excitation at the microphone diaphragm corresponds to $1 \, \textrm{Pa}$. Thus, after you calculate the RMS value of your signal, as described above, all you have to do is to compare it to the sensitivity factor to see whether your value is equal to, larger or smaller than what corresponds to $1 \, \textrm{Pa}$ and by how much.
In linear values, this comparison corresponds to a division like
$$ z = \frac{y_{\textrm{RMS}}}{G_{\textrm{sens}}} \tag{4} \label{4} $$
where $G_{\textrm{sens}}$ is the “linear" value of the sensitivity factor. The $z$ value should represent how much larger or smaller the pressure that generetated the output of your microphone is, compared to $1 \, \textrm{Pa}$, which in practice is the pressure you measured since you compare to $1 \, \textrm{Pa}$. As an example, if $z = 1.38$, the measured pressure would correspond to
$$ p = z * 1 \, \textrm{Pa} = 1.38 * 1 \, \textrm{Pa} = 1.38 \, \textrm{Pa} $$
You have the sensitivity in $\textrm{dB}$, which means that you could either convert the sensitivity to a linear scale, perform the calculations and then convert back to $\textrm{dB}$ if you’d like or do the whole processing in the logarithmic scale. Starting from eq.\eqref{4} we can calculate the $z$ value in $\textrm{dB}$ like
$$ \begin{split}
L_{\textrm{SPL}} & = 10 \log_{10} \left( z \right) = \\
& = 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{y_{\textrm{RMS}}}{G_{\textrm{sens}}} \right) = \\
& = 10 \log_{10} \left( y_{\textrm{RMS}} \right) - 10 \log_{10} \left(G_{\textrm{sens}} \right) = \\
& = L_{\textrm{y}} - L_{\textrm{G}}
\end{split} \tag{5} \label{5} $$
where $L_{\textrm{y}}$ and $L_{\textrm{G}}$ correspond to $y_{\textrm{RMS}}$ and $G_\textrm{sens}$ expressed in $\textrm{dB}$.
So, eq.\eqref{5} shows that what you have to do is to convert the RMS value $y_{\textrm{RMS}}$ to the $\textrm{dB}$ scale and then subtract from it the sensitivity factor. It is also important to note that after the conversion both $L_{\textrm{y}}$ and $L_{\textrm{G}}$ must be in $\textrm{dB}_{\textrm{FS}}$, which is the “unit” of the sensitivity factor you are given.
3.Remarks
In theory, this is enough for you to get what you need. However, this may not be the case and I may be way off. Since you don’t provide much information, I had to make lots of assumptions and some of them may not stand. More specifically, I can’t be sure how the correction curve is supposed to be used (is it even a frequency response curve, is it just magnitude, etc.).  Additionally, the sensitivity factor may refer to Root-Mean-Square (RMS) values, so its application in the way I describe it may not be correct. 
 If you provide more information maybe I could suggest a more appropriate solution (which hopefully be correct as well). 
A couple of things to note here regarding the sensitivity factor. First of all, the sensitivity factor value you provided in the question does not match the one you provided in the comments, which is somewhat concerning.
Second, both values you provide are rather high! If a $94 \, \textrm{dB}_{\textrm{SPL}}$ signal would reach about $-2 \, \textrm{dB}_{\textrm{FS}}$ that means that you only have two more $\textrm{dB}$ until your microphone/system peaks! To put this into context, a sinewave with an RMS value of $94 \, \textrm{dB}_{\textrm{SPL}}$ has a crest factor, which shows how higher than the RMS value is the peak value, of $3 \, \textrm{dB}$. That means that a (co)sinusoid excitation of pressure of $1 \, \textrm{Pa}$ will exceed the full scale and distort!
I strongly suggest you double-check all the values you have and/or any calculations involved. It could also be good to contact the manufacturer to get some more information. They may have more information in user manuals, or some other documents providing information on how to process the data coming out of their equipment.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
